# How many free chests can I stack up?

Tags: clash-royale

I've noticed that overnight I usually get 2 free chests that become ready to be unlocked. When I open the first, the second then becomes available. Is there a limit to how many free chests I can stack this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can stack a maximum of 2 free chests :

> - Uncollected chests will stack (maximum 2) for unlock the next time the player is online.
> - After you have 2 free chests waiting, the timer for the next Free Chest will be stopped until you collect one of your waiting Free
>     Chests.

Source : [Clash Royal Wikia Chests' page](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Chests)

Comment: To add to the answer, I think the Crown Chest stacks the same way (every 24 hours, tho)